# Adicionando Campos no Corpo de um Email PHP

Tags: php

O problema é que tenho um formulário de contato, funcionando tudo certo, porém preciso que ele contenha mais campos no corpo da mensagem do email.

Por exemplo, tenho alguns campos como empresa, telefone, etc... Precisaria que, no corpo do email, tenham eles também.

Vamos a situação atual do `CODE PHP`

```
    <?php
    $name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $from = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $subject    = "Contato via Site"; 
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
    $to         = "xx@xx.com";

    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
    $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

    $header = implode("\r\n", $headers);
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {

    ?>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        alert("Mensagem enviada.");
        </script>
        <script language='javascript'>history.back()</script>;
        <?
    }

    ?>
```

Infelizmente, meu conhecimento em PHP é praticamente nulo.

Resumindo:

Tenho um formulário de contato, nele é enviado apenas um campo no corpo do email, o de mensagem. Necessito adicionar mais 3 campos no corpo, Nome, Empresa e Telefone.

Comment: Crie uma string formatada e atribua a `$message`. Se quiser depois pode montar um template mais incrementado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somente ***concatene*** as `Strings`:

```
$message .= $nome . "\n";
$message .= $empresa . "\n";
$message .= $telefone;
```

Comment: Funcionou, porém no copo do email só aparece a mensagem e o nome, empresa e telefone não

Comment: já tem estes campos no `HTML`? e se já estiverem verifica se estão chegando os valores no `PHP` !

Comment: deu certo amigo, obrigado de novo haha